# Getting sample rate on an iPhone

Tags: ios, avaudiosession

I have an app that uses `AVAudioSession` to record audio and analyze it to determine frequencies for tuning purposes.  The problem is that the sample rate reported by `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().sampleRate` does not correspond to the actual recording rate.

On some devices (iPhone SE and iPad Mini 2) the reported sample rate is 44,100, which matches the actual data.
But on some other devices (iPhone 6S, iPhone 8) the system reports a sample rate of 48,000, yet the samples returned only make sense if they're interpreted as if they were recorded at 44,100 samples per second.

I've tried controlling the sample rate with `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setPreferredSampleRate()`, but that doesn't seem to have any effect at all.

Why doesn't the reported rate match the actual data?

Here's some code:

```
class Myrecorder: NSObject, AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate  {

    let session : AVCaptureSession!

    override init() {
        session = AVCaptureSession()
        super.init()
    }

    enum SetupResult {
        case OK, noInput, noPermission, internalError, waiting
    }

    var isSetup:Bool = false

    func setup( callback:@escaping (()->Bool)) -> SetupResult {
        do {
            let sharedInstance = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            try sharedInstance.setCategory( AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord )
        } catch {
            return SetupResult.internalError
        }
        let device = AVCaptureDevice.default( for: AVMediaType.audio )
        guard (device != nil) else {
            return SetupResult.noInput
        }
        let status = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(  for:AVMediaType.audio )
        guard status != .denied else {
            return SetupResult.noPermission
        }
        guard status != .notDetermined else {
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.audio ){ granted in
                _ = callback()
            }
            return SetupResult.waiting
        }
        var input : AVCaptureDeviceInput
        do {
            try device!.lockForConfiguration()
            try input = AVCaptureDeviceInput( device: device! )
            device!.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch {
            device!.unlockForConfiguration()
            return SetupResult.internalError
        }
        let output = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()
        output.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: Intonia.realTimeQueue)
        session.beginConfiguration()
        guard session.canAddInput( input ) else {
            return SetupResult.internalError
        }
        session.addInput( input )
        guard session.canAddOutput( output ) else {
            return SetupResult.internalError
        }
        session.addOutput( output )
        session.commitConfiguration()
        isSetup = true;
        return SetupResult.OK
    }

    static func getSampleRate() -> Double {
        return AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().sampleRate
    }

    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput,
                       didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer,
                       from connection: AVCaptureConnection){
        var buffer: CMBlockBuffer? = nil
        var audioBufferList = AudioBufferList(
            mNumberBuffers: 1,
            mBuffers: AudioBuffer(mNumberChannels: 1, mDataByteSize: 0, mData: nil)
        )
        CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(
            sampleBuffer,
            nil,
            &audioBufferList,
            MemoryLayout<AudioBufferList>.size,
            nil,
            nil,
            UInt32(kCMSampleBufferFlag_AudioBufferList_Assure16ByteAlignment),
            &buffer
        )
        let abl = UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer(&audioBufferList)
        for buff in abl {
            let samples = UnsafeBufferPointer<Int16>(
                start: UnsafePointer(OpaquePointer(buff.mData)),
                count: Int(buff.mDataByteSize)/MemoryLayout<Int16>.size)
            let newSamples = [Int16](samples)
            MyApp.putSamples_A(samples: newSamples )
        }
    }

    func record() {
        MyApp.realTimeQueue.async {
            self.session.startRunning()
        }
    }

    func pause() {
        session.stopRunning()
    }    
}
```

Comment: Wherever you have called `setPrefferedSampleRate()`, have you checked the [return result](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616523-setpreferredsamplerate) to see if it was successful set? And could you explain further by what you mean as *it only makes sense if they were recorded at another sample rate*. Does this mean the audio is played back and sounds like its at a completely different pitch, for example? Or have you checked the audio playback after recording?

Comment: The method signature is `func setPreferredSampleRate(_ sampleRate: Double) throws`.  Note that it doesn't include `: Bool`, which means that it doesn't return a value, in spite of the notation below about a return value.  Swift will not allow me to assign the result to a Bool.  The method never throws, even if I give an unreasonable sample rate to try.

Comment: When I record an open A string on a violin, which is very close to 440 Hz, the frequency analysis tells me the frequency is about 478 Hz.  When it plays back, the note sounds too high.  If I override `sampleRate` to always return 44100, then the analysis is right on.